# certutil export ALL certs using command prompt

Tags: ssl, certificate, ssl-certificate, command-prompt, certutil

I'm currently exporting a single file one at a time. anyone can help revise my  command line to export ALL the certs from my store?

what i need to achieve is: 
1) export **all** certs from my store into a C:\folder

Any help please? :) 
The code has to be done in command prompt and not powershell
Here are my codes 
using serial number

```
   certutil -p password -exportPFX My dawdwb7291313123e2ad34 c:\export\cert.pfx
```

export all certs from store (not working)

```
certutil -store my -exportPDX C:\export
```

Comment: @DanielFisherlennybacon  :)